# How to identify a section in an Evernote's note to update it later

Tags: attributes, xhtml, evernote

I am making an App that automatically creates Notes into Evernote based on a Government API and I need to update these notes if this Government API change something.

But the thing is, Evernote uses a superset of XHTML called ENML and it doesn't allows me to use "id" or "data" attributes in any tag.

My question is how can I identify one tag or section in a Note that I've created to change/update it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue, so we wrapped the inner HTML with a traceable span like this:

```
<span style="x-your-business-name:section;">Here put the inner HTML content</span>
```

At this point it's just XHTML traversing and updating.
The span doesn't influence in any way the display of the Evernote note.

Comment: I don't see a better way...
A bit off topic but it could be useful, here's a little tool to play with enml : http://enml-editor.ping13.net/

Comment: I don't see a better way either. Thank you @Ciprian, I was using something like that, a div with a display:none, but your solution will work better.